# Static method doesn't return value

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, vk-sdk

What am I doing wrong? Once the execution goes outside `VKRequest.Dispatch`, `tmp` looses data and returns `null`.

**Update**

```
public class GroupClass
{
    private static LinkedList<GroupClass> tmp = new LinkedList<GroupClass>();
    /* some code */
    public static LinkedList<GroupClass> GetGroupList()
    {
        VKRequest.Dispatch<VKList<VKGroup>> ( new VKRequestParameters ( "groups.get", "extended", "1", "filter", "admin, editor, moder", "fields", "photo_100" ), ( res ) =>
        {
            if ( res.ResultCode == VKResultCode.Succeeded && res.Data.count > 0 )
            {
                var item = res.Data.items[0];
                tmp.AddLast( new GroupClass ( item.id, item.name, item.screen_name, item.photo_100 ) );                            
            }
        }); //here
        return tmp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you initializing tmp?

Comment: tmp should be initialized either inside the method or outside as static member. Can you please update your code?

Answer (score 0):

you should copy your variable into local variable before calling a lambda expression. you can find more explaination [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11049430/1735196).

```
public class GroupClass
{
    private static LinkedList<GroupClass> tmp = new LinkedList<GroupClass>();
    /* some code */
    public static LinkedList<GroupClass> GetGroupList()
    {
        var tmp1 = tmp;
        VKRequest.Dispatch<VKList<VKGroup>> ( new VKRequestParameters ( "groups.get", "extended", "1", "filter", "admin, editor, moder", "fields", "photo_100" ), ( res ) =>
        {
            if ( res.ResultCode == VKResultCode.Succeeded && res.Data.count > 0 )
            {
                var item = res.Data.items[0];
                tmp1.AddLast( new GroupClass ( item.id, item.name, item.screen_name, item.photo_100 ) );                            
            }
        }); //here
        return tmp1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, but still `null`