# Lambda functions using defined variables

Tags: c#, lambda, conditional-statements

I would like to test a condition based on values pulled from a configuration file (XML file, FYI). I have something like this to do the checks:

```
List<Condition> conditions = new List<Condition>();
float fVal;
foreach (XmlAttribute attr in conNode.Attributes)
{
    switch (attr.Name.ToLower())
    {
        case "alt_max":
            fVal = float.Parse(attr.Value);
            conditions.Add((t) => { return t.altitude <= fVal; });
            break;
        case "alt_min":
            fVal = float.Parse(attr.Value);
            conditions.Add((t) => { return t.altitude >= fVal; });
            break;

....
```

If I had my conditions set up such that both of these conditions were checked, only the last value would survive. IE

```
<condition alt_max="0.3" alt_min="0"/>
```

What I want to do is to see if the value (`t.altitude` in this case) is between 0 and 0.3. What I'm actually doing is testing if the value is identically 0, as it has to be both less than and greater than 0, due to the [fact that references are sent to lambda functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11049302/how-can-i-capture-the-value-of-an-outer-variable-inside-a-lambda-expression). The value fVal in both instances will be 0, so it has to be `>=0` and `<=0`.

I'm really struggling how I can set this up such that I can test my conditions properly. Any suggestions?

Comment: What does "testing if the value is identically 0" mean?

Comment: OK, I'm confused. You say you want to test if the value is between 0 and 0.3 and also to test if it >= 0 and <= 0. Which is it, then?

Comment: I want to test if it is between 0 and 0.3. What I'm was actually doing was testing if it was between 0 and 0, because of lambda function/ reference stuff. In any case, I think the mystery was solved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your lambdas are reusing the variable `fval`, which is defined outside the scope of the `foreach`.

Moving this line:

```
float fVal;
```

inside the `foreach` should make it work the way you want.

Comment: I knew it had to be something really simple... That seems to have done the trick, thanks for saving me another hour of misery trying to solve this!